# Избавиться от защищенного просмотра EXCEL

Tags: excel, office, outlook

В общем, есть всякие отчеты, которые шлются по почте в формате excel и там есть всякие формулы и все такое...

Проблема в том, что если открывать отчет сразу из вложения в Outlook, то он открывается в режиме защищенного просмотра и пользователь должен явно нажать на разрешение, а формулы в этом режиме не работают...

Есть еще вариант вырубить в программе Excel в политиках безопасности это, но этот вариант не подходит...

Можно ли как-нибудь решить эту проблему? Ну скажем, какой-нибудь почтовый адрес сделать доверительным для всех и все такое?

Comment: А в чем проблема нажать на кнопку разрешения? С доверительным почтовым адресом не получится. Только отключить в настройках.

Comment: @TilekSamiev не нравится конечному получателю¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: может здесь будет подходящее решение для вас https://www.wikihow.com/Unprotect-an-Excel-Sheet

Comment: Вряд ли это возможно. Trust Center принимает решение о защищенном просмотре исходя из размещение документа и источника документа. Причем, источник документа из аттачмента Outlook будет как у документа, скачанного с интернета, независимо от отправителя. Либо отключать защищенный режим полностью, либо каждый пользователю необходимо раз подтверждать то, что он находится в здравом уме и знает, что именно он делает, разрешая выполнение VBScript, расчетных формул и прочих потенциально опасных алгоритмов.

Comment: Есть малая вероятность, что подписав документ электронной подписью, сертификат которой добавлен в домене как максимально-надежный, при открытии документа выведет менее грозное уведомление. Этого нет в документации. Но при том он всё равно не начнет выполнять скрипты без подтверждения пользователя.